# Raphael.js text not showing when assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have this weird error, the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to make a Javascript variable which has a Raphael.js text element as 'value'. Problem is the text is not showing. When I just do paper.text, without assigning the object to a variable the text does show. Has anyone encoutered this? I can't seem to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
var messageObject = paper.text(100,100,"test");
```

Comment: Interesting, according to the docs this should work. What version of Raphael.js are you using? http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text

Comment: Also, looks like messageObject should be an Element object. Does calling messageObject.show() do anything?

Comment: It certainly can work fine, eg http://jsfiddle.net/69nzrgwz/ so I would post the rest of the code on a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I found a workaround. The message did not show when I created it, but when I changed the 'text' attribute of the object, it did change.